# Blender Property not Updating While Needed (Python)

Tags: python, list, properties, blender

I am attempting to set a Property using the Blender Python API and add it to a RotationSyncFinalValue **List**. The **List** is set in the way it needs to be, but the Property is not Updating so the list is not showing the value.

Here's the code where I define the Property:

```
atr = bpy.types.Scene
RotationSyncFinalValue = []
atr.RotationSyncValuesList =EnumProperty(
items= RotationSyncFinalValue,
name = "List", 
description = "Select The Action to Do with the Value")
```

Here is where I set The property in the Panel:

```
layout = self.layout
scene = bpy.context.scene
col.prop(scene,"RotationSyncValuesList")
col = layout.column(align=True)
```

And this is my attempt to add a value to the array **RotationSyncFinalValue**

```
fvalue = ('{0:.4f}'.format(value),
'{0:.4f}'.format(value),
'{0:.4f}'.format(value))
RotationSyncFinalValue.extend([fvalue])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the wrong type for the task. An EnumProperty is a single value that must exist in a defined list of acceptable values, the list of items you pass to the constructor is a list of values that are acceptable to the property, values not in the initial list can not be assigned to the property.

I expect you want to look at the example given for [CollectionProperty](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#collection-example) to end up with something like -

```
class RotationSyncValuesType(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    x = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='x', default=0.0)
    y = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='y', default=0.0)
    z = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name='z', default=0.0)

bpy.utils.register_class(RotationSyncValuesType)
bpy.types.Scene.RotationSyncValuesList = \
        bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=RotationSyncValuesType)

fvalue = bpy.context.scene.RotationSyncValuesList.add()
fvalue.x = 1.0
fvalue.y = 1.0
fvalue.z = 1.0

fvalue = bpy.context.scene.RotationSyncValuesList.add()
fvalue.x = 2.0
fvalue.y = 2.0
fvalue.z = 2.0
```

Then in your panel you could use -

```
for p in scene.RotationSyncValuesList:
    row = col.row()
    row.prop(p, 'x')
    row.prop(p, 'y')
    row.prop(p, 'z')
```

As you appear to want three properties with the same value, you should look at using [custom get/set functions](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#get-set-example), this could ensure that all three properties stay in sync (or only store one value), you would add the get/set to the properties in the PropertyGroup class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an array as you mentioned, then you can look in the docs and understand that can't pass a list to this function using an array object.

> array.extend(iterable)
>   Append items from iterable to the end of the array. If iterable is another array, it must have exactly the same type code; if not, TypeError will be raised. If iterable is not an array, it must be iterable and its elements must be the right type to be appended to the array.
>   https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html

If it was a typo and RotationSyncFinalValue is a list, please add more information so we could help you.